# How to perform security check on a given path (from web server) to serve files

Tags: security, winapi, posix, filesystems

I need to write a small file serving component for web server. There are lots of issues serving
files. Because "as-is" serving as big security hole, like this

```
www.somesite.com/../../../../etc/passwd
```

There are many issues including ".." resolving and many others like under windows there are many "unusual ways to refer to some path". Also there are some issues with symbolic links... They may drive us away of document-root.

Is there any good article or material about serving files and performing security checks on them?

Thanks.

P.S.: I need solution mostly for POSIX systems but I need a solution for Win32 as well.

P.P.S:

- Does check for ".." and symbolic links is sufficient for POSIX systems? (As far as I know it does not for Windows)
- As far as I remember Windows provides some kind of API for these purposes, can somebody point to it?

**Why do I need this:**

[CppCMS](http://cppcms.sourceforge.net/) has a simple internal web server for debugging purposes (I had written one), I try to figure out how hard would it be to make this server fully useful for real world (i.e. listen at 80 directly rather then run behind a web server and FastCGI or SCGI connector).

This is a [file serving application](http://cppcms.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/cppcms/framework/branches/refactoring/internal_file_server.cpp?revision=935&view=markup) that I use at this point. It does very primitive checks. I mostly want make it safe.

**My Answer:**

There is an answer https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/FIO02-C.+Canonicalize+path+names+originating+from+untrusted+sources

Seems to be good enough...

In short: use `realpath` under UNIX and `GetFullPathName` under Windows.

**Final note:** if something would suggest more detailed functionality I would accept it (especially for Win32 where path tests are pain-in-...)

Comment: But at least best practices should be ;)

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific about your webserver - is this a proprietary solution or is it based on some open source webserver. I think that most, if not all, webservers already have some sort of safeguards against these type of attacks as they have been around for ages.

Comment: it is FOSS server but not based on existing code.

Answer (score 1):

As for the Windows API offerings, there are a collection of Shell functions that begin with `Path` and `Url` that can help normalize directories, paths, and file names.  For example, [`PathCanonicalize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773569(VS.85).aspx) will help you get an arbitrary path into a standard form.  From there you can do further analysis.

In general, work with a specific list of things to allow, rather than a list of things to disallow.  Bad guys will always think of new things that you didn't anticipate.

Comment: "PathCanonicalize" unfortunately would not work if I pass "../test.txt" it would not remove "../" as it should.

Comment: Is didn't mean to imply that `PathCanonicalize` was a complete solution.  It is one of several functions that can help you normalize a path.  You'd probably have to use it in combination with others.  You might also look at `InternetCrackUrl`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are dealing with Path Traversal - http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal.
That link mainly deals with web applications, but I think that some of the information there will be helpful. I think the best practice on a POSIX system is to chroot and not allow access to a path outside of the root of the application.

Comment: Thanks. I know that chroot is the best approach but it requires root previleges and not availible on Win32